# Is it possible to modify the TI Sensor Tag firmware to make communication between Sensor Tags possible?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, communication, sensors, firmware, texas-instruments

I have several TI Sensor Tag modules. The Sensor Tag can only communicate with Smarphones/computers out of the box. I would like to also make communication between Sensor Tags possible, so that i can exchange  Sensor data between Sensor Tags. Making this possible has significant advantages in my use case.

I have searched for the possibilities to modify the Sensor Tag to add this functionality. It turns out that it's possible to make changes in the firmware. But how extensive can this changes be? Has anyone tried to actually change the firmare to make it possible to communicate between Sensor Tags? Or is this impossible?

If this is impossible, are there other alternative to Sensor Tag which are programmable to communicate with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, SensorTag is a Slave device and cannot be changed to a Master. Thus, it only accepts incoming connections and has not any capability to establish a connection to an another remote device. You can invest in a CC2541 BLE Mini Development Kit from Texas Instruments:

http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2541dk-mini

Since the firmwire of the KeyFob can be changed to either Master or Slave, it will be possible to communicate various KeyFobs with each other. The kit only includes an accelerometer service among all the services in SensorTag, so I don't know how useful it will be in your case.